# Should I have be worrying about selling a mutual fund before keeping it 1 year in an IRA account?

Tags: united-states, taxes, ira, mutual-funds, fees

I am considering selling a mutual fund in a Roth account that I have had for less than a year. Since Roth and traditional IRA accounts are tax sheltered and capital gains only apply when distribution occurs when retirement, should I be worrying about selling the fund before keeping it 1 year for any reason except transaction fees incurred when the fund was bought?

Comment: what are you doing with the proceeds? is it going into another Roth? or are you spending it?

Comment: No need to put in "another Roth." The funds stay in the account for re-investing. This is normal to buy and sell inside these accounts.

Comment: but that is a question only the OP can answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. Can't understand why would you even think about it. The only thing to consider is the early sales fee, if its a NTF fund. Capital gains in the IRA/401k accounts are not taxed **at all**, so there's no difference whether you hold it more than a year or not.